# TypeError: Error #1009 When reordering scenes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm modifying [this project by Carlos Yanez](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-basic-drawing-application-in-flash--active-1627), which is a drawing application.

What I want to do is to simply add a splash screen before showing the actual drawing app, I tried moving the keyframe where the drawing app is at frame 10, but I get an error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Main/convertToBMD()
at Main()
```

I also tried creating a new scene, and re-ordered it so that it will play first, but I get the same error.

Can anyone please help me ?

I attached the file here: [DOWNLOAD FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/57u4gnbb9cla0q5/Problem.zip?dl=0).

Here is also his main tutorial: [TUTORIAL](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-basic-drawing-application-in-flash--active-1627).

Thank you very much in advance.

> > > EDIT:

I tried using loader but encountered a new error: 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method URLRequest.

I made sure that the external SWF is inside the same folder and with correct name (I named it sketch), but still, no luck :(

Here's the code:

```
cont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_6);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader_6:ProLoader;

//This variable keeps track of whether you want to load or unload the SWF
var fl_ToLoad_6:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToLoad_6)
    {
        fl_ProLoader_6 = new ProLoader();
        fl_ProLoader_6.load(new URLRequest("sketch.swf"));
        addChild(fl_ProLoader_6);
    }
    else
    {
        fl_ProLoader_6.unload();
        removeChild(fl_ProLoader_6);
        fl_ProLoader_6 = null;
    }
    // Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
    fl_ToLoad_6 = !fl_ToLoad_6;
}
```

Comment: You got that error because when your animation is starting the `colors` object didn't even exist (it's `null`) as it exists only in the frame 10. You can avoid that error by moving the code of your document class constructor to another method which will be called when the user close / hide the splash window, for example ...

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply! I've been waiting the whole day :D I'm sorry but I'm not that proficient in flash coding, can you please instruct me on how to change it? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Another example, maybe more easy, is to create your splash in another layer on the top of the existing one, in the frame 1, and when you click it, you hide (or remove) the splash to show your main content ... Just take some minutes to try something ... there are really many manners to do that ...

Comment: Oh yes, I thought about it, I haven't tried it but it might work. But the truth is, what I really want to do is to make a multi-functional app, that has a home screen, with buttons leading to a gallery page, and this drawing app, each on its own scene, and in this case, I can't because it won't let me re-order the scenes, I just want the scene that contains my home screen to play first, but I always get the error. :(

Comment: In that case, it's maybe better to load the paint app SWF just when you need it. In your main app, you click the "paint" button and using a [`Loader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) object you can load the appropriate SWF and remove it later ...

Comment: That might not work since I'm doing this for android air. I modified the drawing app to fit and work on android and I did it, I just can't find a way to add my home screen page. Oh gosh thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Don't worry about Android. That should work everywhere, just do it correctly.

Comment: I did what you suggested. But I encountered another problem: 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method URLRequest. I updated the infos ablove.